# ValueError at /profiles/user-profile/ Field 'id' expected a number but got 'handsome'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Well I am trying to add or remove user from follower list of particular user and user to toggle and profile of user if correct but it showing me this error when i hit on a follow button . How can i fix it ?

models.py

```
class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def toggle_follow(self, request_user, username_to_toggle):
        profile_ = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username__iexact=request_user)
        user = request_user
        is_following = False
        if username_to_toggle in profile_.follower.all():
            profile_.follower.remove(username_to_toggle)
        else:
            profile_.follower.add(username_to_toggle)
            is_following = True
        return profile_, is_following

        
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follower = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name ='is_following',blank=True,)
    avatar = models.ImageField(("Avatar"), upload_to='displays', default = '1.jpg',height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None,blank = True)
    create_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
   
    objects = ProfileManager()
```

viewspy

```
class UserProfileFollowToggle(View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            username_to_toggle = request.POST.get("username")
            profile_, is_following = UserProfile.objects.toggle_follow(request.user, username_to_toggle)
            return redirect(f'/profiles/{username_to_toggle}')
```

traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/user-profile/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.8.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap3',
 'accounts',
 'posts',
 'profiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1772, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)

The above exception (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'handsome') was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\grapPub\grabpublic\profiles\views.py", line 27, in post
    profile_, is_following = UserProfile.objects.toggle_follow(request.user, username_to_toggle)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\grapPub\grabpublic\profiles\models.py", line 21, in toggle_follow
    profile_.follower.add(username_to_toggle)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 944, in add
    self._add_items(
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 1123, in _add_items
    self.through._default_manager.using(db).bulk_create([
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 492, in bulk_create
    returned_columns = self._batched_insert(
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1230, in _batched_insert
    self._insert(item, fields=fields, using=self.db, ignore_conflicts=ignore_conflicts)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1383, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1326, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1327, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1327, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1268, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 939, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 821, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2365, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(

Exception Type: ValueError at /profiles/user-profile/
Exception Value: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'handsome'.
```

if more detial is require than tell me i will update my question with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def toggle_follow(self, request_user, username_to_toggle):
  profile_ = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=request_user.id)
  is_following = False
  follower = profile_.follower.filter(username__iexact=username_to_toggle).first()
  if follower:
    profile_.follower.remove(follower.id)
  else:
    new_follower = User.objects.get(username__iexact=username_to_toggle)
    profile_.follower.add(new_follower.id)
    is_following = True
  return profile_, is_following
```

Comment: Now it showing me : **AttributeError at /profiles/user-profile/

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'**